# PHP-jQuery: Form with 2 buttons and 2 actions. Second Button is calling the actions of the first button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with 2 actions and whenever I try to execute the second action, the first one gets called for some reason.

The first action is to search and populate the form with some data retrieved from a database. This part works.

The second actions is to submit the form after some additional data is manually entered into the form. For some reason, whenever I click on this second button, the function for the first button gets executed but not the second one.

I have each click function in separate scripts.

**First Function:**

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#register-submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#find-details-btn").click(function(){
     /* validation */
    $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            id: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 11,
            },
            second_id: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            },
            enter_date: {
            required: true,
            },
       },
       messages:
       {
            id:{
                      required: "Message Here.",
                      minlength: "Message Here",
                     },
            second_id:{
                      required: "Message Here.",
                      minlength: "Message Here",
                     },
            enter_date:{
                      required: "Message Here.",
                     },
       },
       submitHandler: checkGetData
       });

   function checkGetData()
   {
        var data = $("#register-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'validate_get_data.php',
        data : data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#detailsmsg").fadeOut();
            $("#find-details-btn").html('<img src="include/btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Searching...');
            $('#find-details-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },

        success :  function()
           {
                //some actions go here to populate data into proper fields.
           }
        });
        return false;
      } 
   });
});
</script>
```

**second script**

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $("#register-submit-btn").click(function(){

            var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update_data.php',
            data : data,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#detailsmsg").fadeOut();
                $("#register-submit-btn").html('<img src="include/btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Sending...');
                $('#register-submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#find-details-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success :  function(data)
               {
//Actions to display a success message after data is inserted goes here.
                    }
                });
                    return false;
            //}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When in click on the register-submit-btn. What I get are the actions of the first script that should be triggered when I click on the find-details-btn. As a matter of fact, even the animation for the find-details-btn is executed when I click on the register-submit-btn.

Any ideas why the second button is working as if it was the first button?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT: Added Form structure per request.**

```
    <form class="register-form" id="register-form" action="" method="POST">             
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label bold">ID</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" maxlength="11" placeholder="Cedula Number" id="first_id" name="first_id" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" name="find-details-btn" id="find-details-btn" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Find Details</button>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" id="detailsmsg">
            <!-- messages goes here -->
        </div>

        <div id="details_found" class="hidden">
        <p class="font-blue bold"> Details Found </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" value="" id="f_name" name="f_name" readonly /> </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Second ID</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" value="" id="second_id" name="second_id" readonly /> 
        </div>
        <p class="font-blue bold"> Enter your details below: </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Details 1</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="details_1" name="details_1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Details 2</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="details_2" name="details_2" /> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Details 3</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="details_3" name="details_3" /> 
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="button" id="register-back-btn" name="register-back-btn" class="btn green btn-outline">Back</button>
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" name="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success uppercase pull-right">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you please include the form structure code? It'll make it much easier for us to find answers for you if we have the complete code to look at :)

Comment: I edited the question and added the form structure. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your second script is that you are calling an AJAX request and want to display a success message. BUT YOU ARE NOT PREVENTING FORM FROM SUBMITTING.

This might be the cause of your problem. When you try to  make an AJAX call, prevent other events which redirects the page to actually view the response. Your code should be something like below.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()

{
    $("#register-submit-btn").click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update_data.php',
            data : data,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#detailsmsg").fadeOut();
                $("#register-submit-btn").html('<img src="include/btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Sending...');
                $('#register-submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#find-details-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success :  function(data)
               {
//Actions to display a success message after data is inserted goes here.
                    }
                });
                    return false;
            //}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is something that will prevent it from submitting and will just send the request to the url.

Now if your data is not getting updated that might be the case with your PHP script. If still you are unable to update your records please debug your PHP script or post your PHP script block for further information.

Happy coding ^_^

Comment: Thank you JugaIK. I get what you're saying but what I don't understand (perhaps you can clarify this for me) is, why is it that if every button has it's own function assigned to it, the functions of the first button (find-details-btn) are being called when I click on the other button but the functions for the second button (register-submit-btn) are not being called at all when clicked? it's like register-submit-btn is acting as find-details-btn.